# Can files and directories be merge-mounted into a docker container such that changes on the host are immediately visible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

A docker container has these files and directories:

```
/foo/
/foo/a.txt
/foo/subdir-1/
/foo/subdir-1/b.txt
```

The host has these files and directories:

```
/bar/
/bar/a.txt
/bar/subdir-1/
/bar/subdir-1/c.txt
```

I want to mount the host's `/bar` onto the container's `/foo` such that the result will be the following in the container:

```
/foo/
/foo/a.txt
/foo/subdir-1/
/foo/subdir-1/b.txt
/foo/subdir-1/c.txt
```

such that the container sees the host's version of `a.txt`, and similarly with other colliding file names. Colliding directories are merged such that the container sees the contents of both.

Furthermore, I want

- if `/bar/a.txt` or `/bar/subdir-1/c.txt` are modified on the host, these modifications are immediately visible in the container
- if a new file `/bar/subdir-1/d.txt` or a new subdirectory `/bar/subdir-2` are created in the host while the container is running, the container will also see these appear

The host and container are both Linux.

I tried this in docker-compose:

```
volumes:
   - /bar:/foo
```

but my container no longer saw `b.txt` since that file is not present in the host.

Is this effect possible using docker-compose?

Comment: No, not out of the box. If you bind mount something into an image in a location that contains files, the files in the image are 'obscured' and not visible. https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container

Comment: This works the same way as any other Unix mount.  If you mounted a USB disk over your home directory, for example, you would see only the USB disk and nothing from your local disk, and there is no way to see both or have write-through behavior.